# Is there a difference between view and tabular expression?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/views) for views defines syntax as follows:

```
let v=() {print x=1, y=2};
```

If I simplify it to

```
let te = print x=1, y=2;
```

it [will be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement) a variable holding a tabular expression.

I found that I can use them interchangeably, expressions work pretty much like (not materialized) views.

```
let te = print x = rand(1000), y = 1;
let v=() {print x = rand(1000), y = 1};
te | join v on y | join te on y | join v on y
```

Is there any performance or other difference between the above options? If no, why do two variants of syntax exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking a very specific use-case, of an ad-hoc function without parameters.
A use-case that does not show the true potential of the syntax.

Yes, they are all tabular expressions.

```
let t = range i from 1 to 3 step 1;
t
```

| i |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBVKErMS09VyFRIK8rPVTBUKMlXMFYoLkktUDC05ioBACb+9holAAAA)

But, can they be constructed by using scalar parameters?

```
let t = (x:int, y:int){range i from x to y step 1};
t(4,7)
```

| i |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBV0Kiwyswr0VGoBFGa1UWJeempCpkKaUX5uQoVCiX5CpUKxSWpBQqGtda8XCUaJjrmmgC8ckXhOwAAAA==)

Or by operating on another tabular expression?

```
let t = (mytab:(x:int, y:int), j:int){mytab | extend z = (x + y) * j};
range i from 1 to 5 step 1
| extend x = toint(rand(10)), y = toint(rand(10))
| invoke t(1000)
```

| i | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 10000 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | 14000 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 3000 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 | 8000 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 5000 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WNPQ7CMBSD90q9g8cEOiQDSxGHKeoDpdAEFQsl/Nydlw4sTJZsf/ZVCOIAMxcOx97kPkR2KFVsh2nV1xriDcmUOOJZgYwtisUG02ffNssQz4KA05JmeDBhhzvlBt82Py4rx6SLRuuj8c7qRfk3KxLiI10EVMM5%20wX0iFjdpwAAAA==)

Are they recognized by operators such as [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)?

```
let t1 = range i from 1 to 3 step 1;
let t2 = range i from 1 to 4 step 1;
let t3 = (){range i from 1 to 5 step 1};
let t4 = view(){range i from 1 to 6 step 1};
let t5 = view(){range i from 1 to 7 step 1};
union withsource=src t*
| summarize count() by src
```

| src | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| t4 | 6 |
| t5 | 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33KTQ6CMBAG0D2n%20JbgrgK6MBwGm1EnoR3TTiH%203d2akBiVuH5vIIUadAi9PxIYhyAOBiqoEZXOMLtieKX1Ymo%20U51TWd1%20Xzu/xxybHEemaTFvvnL7L2/fOXkWj4n1FCUFS10MFroq7ojJuT7wlWAleS0r7C/I%20gRAVnMP/wAAAA==)

or [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)?

```
let t1 = range i from 1 to 3 step 1;
let t2 = range i from 1 to 4 step 1;
let t3 = (){range i from 1 to 5 step 1};
let t4 = view(){range i from 1 to 6 step 1};
let t5 = view(){range i from 1 to 7 step 1};
search in (t*) *
| summarize count() by $table
```

| $table | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| t4 | 6 |
| t5 | 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33KvQ6CMBQG0J2n%20AaHlq0COhgfppCrNOmPaS8aQd9dTEgISDzzscRghTOi9leCwSUGBwUOKJCYblCnzH7TfjOVy1SMScjh91XTe0%20xHOPd0GMzH1a5%20pePc06kY9PCeAjOJfLshdQ5p6PpCU3oPAuJ%20okd69rSB%20fOdMf7AAAA)

Comment: Wow, that's a cool set of examples. Still... as for the performance question, are there any differences?

Comment: It's the same tabular expression, why should there be any? Even if a function would require some additional parsing for its parameters, we're still talking here about micro-second level, pre-execution of the tabular expression. Not sure where this question is coming from.